# Como mandar dos parámetros, uno de un select y otro de un input para obtener datos de mysql y colocar el dato de una columna en otro input

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

estoy empezado la programación web con php y mysql y tengo un problemita en una tarea, lo que quiero hacer es que al seleccionar un dato de un campo select y escribir en campo de texto me mande  a llamar el a una base de datos mysql que coincidan con esos dos parámetros y que me coloque un dato de una columna obtenida de la consulta en un input.

El código ajax que tengo es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#promotor').on('keyup',function(){
var promotorID = $(this).val();
var programaID = $("#tipoprograma option:selected").text();
  if(promotorID){
  $.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'datos/ajaxData.php',
  data:{'id_promotor='+promotorID,'id_programa='+programaID},
  success:function(html){
  $('#enlace').html(html);
  }
  });
}else{
  $('#enlace').html('Escriba un promotor');
  console.log(data);
}
});
});
```

Y el codigo del archivo que procesa esa peticion es la siguiente:

```
require_once "Conexion.php";
$database = new Conexion();

if(isset($_POST['id_promotor']) && !empty($_POST['id_programa'])){
     $query = mysqli_query($database->connection,"select * from Promocion where nombre = ".$_POST['id_promotor']." and tipo_programa = ".$_POST['id_programa']." ");
        $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
    
        if($rowCount > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row['nom_enlace'];
        }

        }else{
        echo 'Promotor no disponible';
        }

    }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, estoy desesperado o si tienen una mejor solución les quedaré eternamente agradecidos.

Saludos

Comment: Y cual seria el problema???

Comment: Saludos. Tu `data:{'id_promotor='+promotorID,'id_programa='+programaID}` debe ser `data:{id_promotor: promotorID, id_programa: programaID}`; lo anterior claro esta; asumiendo los datos a enviar los recibes correctamente; personalmente te sugiero usar `data:JSON.stringify{id_promotor: promotorID, id_programa: programaID})` (ver https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp ). Recuerda en lo sucesivo incluir mensajes de error y/o lo que notas debe ocurrir y esta ocurriendo; así se puede orientar más puntualmente que te esta deteniendo.

Comment: Yo pienso que la peticion tendrias que hacerlo con un `onchange` en el `select` porque usar un `keyup` en el `input` para realizar esa peticion, lo veria ineficiente

Comment: Gracias por responder amigos y por sus recomendaciones voy a probar cada opción. El problema es que no me muestra ningún resultado , el select lo estoy llenando de una tabla de mi BD y mi consulta necesita el parámetro del select y lo que escribo en el input, todo esto para mostrar el registro de una columna en otro campo de texto